# Bug in Chrome wrapping of nested spans in Japanese?

Tags: html, google-chrome, layout, text

Chrome does not seem to be wrapping Japanese text properly when spans are nested. See http://jsfiddle.net/MRAS4/2/. This is reproducible in Safari but not Firefox.

In the below, the red circled area is incorrectly left vacant and everything following is shuffled down to the next line.

[image]

The gray-shaded area is the first span, and the blue-shaded area is the nested span. As far as I can tell, it seems that Chrome is refusing to break either before or after the inner span, with the result that everything gets pushed to the next line.

I can set `word-break` to `break-all` and this "solves" the problem, but that also disables correct Japanese line-breaking behavior, such as full-stops not coming at the beginning of the line.

I suppose this is just a bug in Webkit that I should report?

Comment: Unable to dupe in the Chrome 29 beta.

Comment: Reproducible in Chrome 28. Maybe it's already been fixed in their next release then?